# C#/Mongo. Update each record with same field differently

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a list of objects, and each object has an order.

I want to update each object's record differently. I tried doing the following instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618427/update-liststring-in-mongodb), but the accepted answer adds a list to my order field rather than the latest value.

What I want to do is to update each record's order property differently.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageRecords.Count; i++)
{
    orderList.Add(increment * (i + 1));
}
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Order", orderList[i]);
```

[EDIT]

I want to get a record that looks like

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "order": 1
}
{
 "id": 2,
 "order": 2
}
{
 "id": 3,
 "order": 3
}
```

What I am currently getting is this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "order": [1, 2, 3]
}
{
 "id": 2,
 "order": [1, 2, 3]
}
{
 "id": 3,
 "order": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: you need to be specific on what outcome you want

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class for the updates as follows:

```
class MyUpdate
{
    public FilterDefinition<MyOrder> Filter {get;set;}
    public UpdateDefinition<MyOrder> Update { get; set; }
}
```

Then make a list of it and fill it with the filters and updates:

```
var myUpdates = new List<MyUpdate>()
{
    new MyUpdate(){ Filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Id, ObjectId.Parse("5a33b9bdec34269d4c03c939")),
        Update = Builders<MyOrder>.Update.Set(x=> x.Order, "First Order") },
    new MyUpdate(){ Filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Id,ObjectId.Parse("5a33b9ceec34269d4c03c941")),
        Update = Builders<MyOrder>.Update.Set(x=> x.Order, "Second Order") },
    new MyUpdate(){ Filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Id, ObjectId.Parse("5a33b9daec34269d4c03c944")),
        Update = Builders<MyOrder>.Update.Set(x=> x.Order, "Third Order") }
}
```

Note that my Ids are of the type `ObjectId`.

Then you can call the `UpdateOne` in a loop like this:

```
foreach (var update in myUpdates)
{
    var modified = context.MyOrder.UpdateOne(update.Filter, update.Update).ModifiedCount;
}
```